# How does render() determine url to use when rendering template

Tags: django

- Have experimented with the view function below.
- It matches and renders fine.
- But have not been able to figure out via experiment/search
  how the url is determined that is used when the template is rendered.
- The matching/incoming url is "rec/play/new/".
- render() seems to use this same url when it renders e.g. "rec/play/new/"
- Is that always the case? How does determine to use this url. I thought via request, but even when the request is blanked out, it has no impact:
  return render(None, 'play/edit.html', {'form': RecForm()})
  -- Still renders with url "rec/play/new/". How is it doing that?

  ```
  def rec_new(request):
      #matching url is "rec/play/new/"
      if request.method == "POST":
      form = RecForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         model = form.save(commit=False)
         model.save()
           return redirect('detail', pk=model.pk)
      else:
           return render(request, 'play/edit.html', {'form': RecForm()})
  ```

Answer (score 2):

`render()` isn't determining the url. When your browser sends a request for a certain url, django is figuring out which template populated with which data should be returned for that url.

`request` is used to help generate the content. But note that you don't have to use `render()`, and can instead return a `HTTPResponse()` directly:

```
return HttpResponse(content, content_type, status)
```

[HTTP Response documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects)

Comment: Ah -- I was not picturing the browswer/client/url sitting and waiting for our response with url "X". And "X" not changing -- got it. Only redirect/other would change the url. Thx pk.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the Django request response cycle. Take a look at this picture:
[image: Django request-response cycle]

If I use your words, `render()` doesn't use `url`, it's the other way around. First request goes through request middleware, then url resolution, view middleware and then it gets to view and template rendering and finishes with response middleware processing. After all this completes, server transfer content to your browser.

In basic terms, `url` defines what `view` will be processed and `view` defines what `template` will be rendered.

Comment: Thx Borut; I think maybe I got it. The browser (current url) is preserved (waiting) and does not change; unless e.g. we redirect. thx.